# Chart Data Table Sizing Issue

Tags: vba, excel

I am running a macro to resize my plot area to make all graphs uniform within a report. However, when resizing the plot area the Chart Data Table resizes as well and the Labels for the rows in the Data Table become text wrapped. This issue is fixed if I manually resize the Plot Area slightly and then the text is fixed and is autofit and no longer text wrapped to take up three or four lines. Any way to fix this? This is my current code.

```
Sub Color_Loop_Series()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim ser As Series

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
cht.Activate
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
ActiveChart.Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
ActiveChart.Legend.Font.Size = 9
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
Selection.Width = 380
Selection.Left = 11
Selection.Top = 3
Selection.Height = 250
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Position = xlAxisPositionLeft
ActiveChart.DataTable.Font.Size = 5.5
Next cht
Next sht
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to duplicate your problem using Excel 2010 by recording a macro while moving the plot area.  When running the recorded macro the data table legend resized and text wrapped.  I was not able to find any direct handle for the data table legend but did find that both `.Left` and `.InsideLeft` affect word wrapping.

Here is your code, *modified a little to remove all `Active` statements.*

```
Sub Color_Loop_Series()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
    Dim cht As ChartObject
    Dim ser As Series

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
            With cht.Chart
                .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
                .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
                .Legend.Font.Size = 9
                .DataTable.Font.Size = 5.5
                .Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Position = xlAxisPositionLeft
            End With

            With cht.Chart.PlotArea
                .Width = 380
                .Height = 250
                .Left = 11
                .Top = 3
                .InsideLeft = 80    '<- Adjust this value
            End With
        Next cht
    Next sht
End Sub
```

---

Results when using `.InsideLeft`

[image]

---

Results when not using `.InsideLeft`

[image]

Comment: So I've tried running this now but I am getting a failure at

    .Width = 350

It is saying it has failed at this section for a few of the charts. I don't know why.

Comment: Also, does it work when you comment out `.InsideLeft`?  I'm guessing it's unrelated.

Comment: you were right it was an unrelated issue that occurred when the ActieChart portion was removed but i found a fix for it. Thanks!